# Why do I not get an ICMP message in responce when doing an UDP scan with nmap?

Tags: networking, nmap

We had a lab where we scanned a vulnerable system where alot of ports were closed, so it returned alot of ICMP messages as expected and it took a long time. But then I tried to scan my own Debian 10 system I expected to see the same because I have not setup a firewall as far as I know, but it went very fast, only recieved ICMP messages from the open ports. I inspected it with wireshark to be sure, and yes, no ICMP responces.

But why? Should I not get many ICMP messages aswell? Is there something with my OS that prevent a scan like "nmap -sU XX.XX.XX.XX"?

Comment: Were you in the same network as your Debian?

Comment: No, the one that responded with all the ICMP messages is a metasploit machine that is installed on a virtualbox, so the network is the same but through the virtualbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default linux kernel behaviour is to respond with ICMP type 3, so either you *do have* a packet filter silently dropping you packets somwhere between nmap and the target or the responding machine is routing icmp responses to an interface, from which they can't reach you.

Comment: *Or* it might be that your packets are reaching the target just fine, but the packet filter in between is dropping the returning ICMP type 3 packets. Blocking all ICMP is stupid and causes established technologies like Path MTU Discovery to fail, but unfortunately all too common. If you feel the need to do something to ICMP in a firewall, try rate-limiting it first if possible, and block various ICMP types selectively instead of just dropping all ICMP, please! (Many modern OSs will consider sending out ICMP responses a low-priority task and/or rate-limit it automatically anyway.)